# Gmaps.build('Google') TypeError: undefined is not a function Gmaps4Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

Using this gem: https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails

I am trying to update to the newest gem version and experiencing a problem calling

```
Gmaps.build('Google') -> TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

but Gmaps is defined:

```
Gmaps -> Object {triggerOldOnload: function, loadMaps: function}
```

I have all followed the steps in the repo for the asset pipeline. Not sure what's causing this error.

Comment: you dont use the proper version, update to v2

Comment: Sorry but I am using gmaps4rails (2.1.2) <- Taken from gemfile.lock

Comment: So you have legacy js somewhere because the code you have is from v1.x

Comment: Ok, I deleted the old gmaps4rails folder from my javascripts assets, and it's working now. Thanks @apneadiving .. Please provide your answer so I can approve it.

Comment: By the way, I really like the new version! Much easier to use.

Comment: Nice to read, thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have legacy js somewhere because the code you have is from v1.x

You should just remove it.